# timestamp to date changes date timezone

Tags: php, date

I have a date 31/12/2013 00:00:00 stored as timestamp 1388440800

When I make the conversion using date() function I'm getting 30/12/2013 (1388361600)

somehow on conversion is changing my timezone or something

There is a way to convert it to date the way it is without any changes?

the server default timezone is Europe/London

Edit 1: The thing is that the date is stored as timestamp through extjs and there I'm getting the right date

Comment: 1388440800 *does* correspond to Dec. 30 *in London*, that's perfectly correct. http://3v4l.org/clqrK You are expecting the wrong thing and/or have stored the wrong timestamp.

Comment: In fact it is Mon, 30 Dec 2013 22:00:00 GMT. Try it here and see http://www.epochconverter.com and 1388440600 = Mon, 30 Dec 2013 21:56:40 GMT

Comment: hmmm.. ok.. this makes sense I guess. I was hopping there might be a solution that is somehow timezone independent. I think extjs is using my local timezone instead the server one and this is messing up everything. This might have been a stupid question, but helped me a lot.. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use `DateTime` class, you wouldn't need to worry about in which timezone is server:

```php
# when you input @timestamp as parameter, timezone UTC is set
$date = new DateTime('@1388440800');

# then convert your datetime to your specific timezone
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/London'));

# format it anyway you need it
echo $date->format('c');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this function "settimezone", more informations at:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php